# Is it a mandatory to attend company's events after office hour?

Tags: company-culture, events, singapore

As in title, is it a mandatory for every employees to attend company's events after office hour?

It's not an employee gathering event, but more on company's.

Comment: What country? That may affect answers, as may your employment contract.

Comment: As in my employment contract, there is nothing states about it. Currently I live at Singapore.

Comment: What kind of events?

Comment: I always seem to have "long standing prior arrangements" for those days.

Comment: "It's not an employee gathering event, but more on company's" -- what does this mean?

Comment: @Brandin its basicly not a employee initiated diner Party.

Comment: Yup, it's a company initiated event to do announcement to all employees.

Comment: To know whether it's mandatory you should really ask your boss. e.g. "Boss, on Thursday I really have to leave here on time, but we have that announcement planned after closing. Is it all right if I'm not here for it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no it's not mandatory. But some companies expect people to attend and can penalise them if they don't.

Location does make a big difference as well, my limited experience with Singapore is that companies there can be very regimented and quite rigid in many things. There is probably a strong expectation that you comply, but it's up to the actual company how they deal with it if you don't. Most places I have worked you just say you have personal business to attend to, and that's it.

In my own country many businesses act like they own the employees and quite regularly insist they do things out of company hours and will sack low level staff if they don't, but as far as I know it's not that strict in Singapore.

Comment: not familiar with Singapore, but in the US, it can damage your career if you don't attend.